# How to load many files regularly and pick up where it left off?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In a directory arrive many files to load by Spring Batch, regularly.
My Spring Batch Jar is launched by an external scheduler.
If there is an error in a file, I'd like that the other files be loaded and, that the loading pick up where it left off for the file with error (after having correct my file)

This is my very simple example :

---

### SpringBatchSimpleTestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBatchSimpleTestApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchSimpleTestApplication.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchSimpleTestApplication.class, args)));
    }
    
}
```

---

### PersonJobConfiguration.java

```
public class PersonJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Value("classpath*:person*.csv")
    private Resource[] inputFiles;

    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<Person> multiResourceItemReader1() {
    return new MultiResourceItemReaderBuilder<Person>()                  
        .name("multiResourceItemReader1")
            .delegate(reader1())
            .resources(inputFiles)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader1() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>() 
        .name("personItemReader")
        .lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer()  {{ setNames("firstName", "lastName", "age'"); setColumns(new Range(1,4), new Range(5,6),new Range(7)); }})
        .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{ setTargetType(Person.class); }})
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer1(DataSource dataSource) {         
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setAssertUpdates(true);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());

        return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job person_job(JobEndListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("person_job")
            //.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(multiResourceItemReader1())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }

}
```

---

### Person.java

```
public class Person {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String age;
    

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName, String age) {
        super();
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "firstName: " + firstName + ", lastName: " + lastName;
    }

}
```

---

My problem :

- If I use ".incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())" in the Job, a new Job is created at each execution of my project. Consequently, if a loading failed, it picks up from the beginning of the file but not where it left off.
- If I don't use ".incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())" in the Job, it works, it picks up where it left off, but, if I add new files to load, they aren't loaded beacause there isn't a new job created.

How to load some files arriving regularly in a same directory ?
Is the best way to use ".incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())" in this case ? If no, how to ?

To pick up a loading where it left off, I don't want to enter each job id to restart. I want that it be done automatically.
Do I have to get the failed jobs in database, then, restart them ?
If so, how to ?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards.

Comment: A job instance should be defined for a *fixed* dataset (for restartability) and this is done by wisely choosing a set of identifying job parameters, what are your job parameters?  An incrementer is used when there is a well defined sequence of job instances, do you have such a sequence? Do you really need an incrementer?

Comment: My principle :
- Many files whith the same structure arrive in a folder 
- Spring Batch is launched : it loads all the files of the folder in database.
- Then, new files whith the same structure arrive in the same folder 
- Spring Batch is launched again and must load the files in database.
- and so on...

In this case, can we say that there is a well defined sequence of job instances ?
Do I have to use an incrementer ?

(I don't use JobParameters for the moment)

Comment: How is your job launched? Is it based on a regular schedule or via a custom event? Can you share the code of how you launch jobs? `If there is an error in a file, I'd like that the other files be loaded and, that the loading pick up where it left off for the file with error (after having correct my file)`: Spring Batch has to know how to identify a fixed data set to be able to restart where it left off, so you need to specify how to uniquely identify a job instance using identifying job parameters. The choice of job parameters is crucial to correctly design a restartable Spring Batch job.

Comment: I've just added more precisions to my problem.

Comment: ok thanks. I added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes things complicated here is that a single job is processing multiple files at the same time.

Following the Unix philosophy of making one thing do one thing and do it well, I recommend making each job process a single file. You can create a scheduled method that reads the directory content and launches a job for each file (the unique file name being an identifying job parameter). Successfully loaded files can be moved to another directory. Now if a job fails, it does not affect the loading of other files, and in the next run, the failed file will be restarted where it left off.

This approach has a number of advantages:

- Scalability: It allows you to run multiple jobs in parallel (the MultiResource reader approach will load files in serial)
- Fault-tolerance: It allows you to restart a failed file where it left off
- It does not require an incrementer.
- Etc

The choice of job parameters is crucial to correctly design a restartable Spring Batch job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

If I understand well :
- I must create as many scheduled methods as I have directories where I have files to load.
- Then, each of these methods browse the files of the directories and for each file,  I must launch a job with in parameter the name of the file to load.
- If a loading fails, I must correct my file and relaunch Spring Batch with in parameter the name of the file in error.

Is it correct ? Is it the best way to do ?

Comment: everything is correct except having a scheduled method for each directory. I don't understand why you would need that. The scheduled method can traverse one or multiple directories containing input files and launch a job for each file. Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I thought to do one scheduled method by directory because I wanted launch loadings at different moments, for performance reasons.

Comment: Hello, I tried like you said to launch a job by file. I put each time the filename in JobParameter **and only it**. It loads well all my files. However, if I try to load a file already loaded, Spring Batch loads it a second time. Is it normal ?

Comment: No it should not, unless the previous run failed. If you try to run the same job instance that was completed for a given file you should get a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`. Are you sure there is no incrementer that adds another parameter?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well (somebody had changed my Spring Batch tables). Have a nice end of day.