# Spring batch : MultiResourceItemReader outcome management

Tags: spring-batch

I faced recently a change in a spring batch requirement : had to switch from a single file input (provided by a tier-application), to a multiple-file input (a directory in which to read from).
So far, no big deal, researches done, I've put a new MultiResourcesItemReader in place, and this works fine. But when it comes to error management, some questions started to raise.

Is there a way to handle errors from each file processed separately ? I feel like MultiResourcesItemReader offers a great way to handle multiple file, but handles them like "a bloc". Meaning, everything either fails or succeeds.

I've come to write a CustomSkipPolicy to help me manage errors that could occur from a read processing, but I hardly know how to bind it to the relevant file. And if my SkipPolicy helps me to "snipe" precisely which line of my file is failing, I'm then struggling treating each file separately according to status.

And this lead me to my second point : how I can move specificly a file that has either failed or succeeded into a specific directory (like /failed or /success) in this MultiResourcesItemReader context (since the stepExecution does not seem to provide the currenly processed resources) ?

TLDR : my ultimate goal here is to provide some QA users a meaningful way to correct files up : which one fails and why it fails, in the simplest way.

Summary:

- file1 ok > move to /success
- file2 ok but 1 line fails > integrate what's ok > log/write errors > move to /failed
- file3 fail > write errors > move to /failed.

I've found pieces of answer here and there but does not entirely help with my requirements.
Hope I've been clear enough.
CMZ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load many files regularly and pick up where it left off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726042/how-to-load-many-files-regularly-and-pick-up-where-it-left-off)

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine. Thank you for your answer. This looks interesting, I'll update if it helped.